# извлечение данных из Дата фрейм с несколькими колонками

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Как правильно извлечь данные из дата фрейма? Код ниже не работает:

```
for Device, Host in df_r0[["Device","Host"]]:
    print ( Device, Host)
```

В самом дата фрейме два столбца с заголовками Device и Host. В одном название маршрутизатора, в другом его адрес.

Comment: `print(df_r0[["Device","Host"]])` ? или, раз уж в датафрейме всего два столбца, `print(df_r0)` ?

Comment: так я уже делал ) мне нужно извлечь информацию из каждого столбца отдельно  и использовать её.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы последовательно получить значения из столбцов, можно воспользоваться iterrows(). Генератор возвращает индекс и значения столбцов из одного ряда. Можно сразу их  и распаковать

```
for i, (Device, Host) in df_r0[["Device","Host"]].iterrows() :
    print (Device, Host)
```

Comment: спасибо. Этот ответ помог. Но не понимаю как это работает: for i, (Device, Host) и причём тут " i ". Но спасибо )

Comment: Генератор возвращает индекс и значения столбцов из одного ряда. i - это как раз индекс. а дальше кортеж переменных в которые вы хотите распаковать содержимое строки

Comment: теперь понятно почему ошибка была с количеством значений. Спасибо